# Replacing Bookmark Range within Word document with formatted (HTML) text

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm using Office Interop with MS Word (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word) to modify a template, replacing bookmarks within the template with sections of text. I have a method that does this:

```
public void ReplaceBookmarkText(Bookmark bookmark, string newValue)
{
    if (newValue != null) {
        bookmark.Range.Text = newValue;
    }
}
```

This works fine for plain text. I want to create a new method, where the second parameter can be HTML code, and the code is converted to formatted text, which replaces the `Range`'s text. If I could have things my way, I'd write something like this:

```
public void ReplaceBookmarkTextWithHtml(Bookmark bookmark, string html)
{
    if (newValue != null) {
        bookmark.Range.Html = html;
    }
}
```

Of course, `Html` isn't a member of the `Range` class. I've also tried the following:

```
public void ReplaceBookmarkTextWithHtml(Bookmark bookmark, string html)
{
    if (newValue != null) {
        bookmark.Range.FormattedText = html;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work as the `FormattedText` property is of type `Range`.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I eventually came up with. It involve performing a copy and paste.

```
public void ReplaceBookmarkTextWithHtml(Bookmark bookmark, string html)
{
    if (html != null) {
        Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Html, ClipboardFormatter.Html(html));
        bookmark.Range.PasteSpecial(DataType: WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to do it is by saving the html text into a temporary .html file and then inserting the file inside the doc, i.e.:

```
bookmark.Range.InsertFile("tmp.html");
```